# How to use session_set_cookie_params path with dynamic prefix?

Tags: php

I am having a website with admin panel, which is located in path:
`/<language_code>/manager/`, for example:

```
/en/manager/
/ru/manager/
/fr/manager/
```

etc..

I want to set a single cookie for this admin panel, but separated from frontend. So, I am setting the `path` parameter for this.

My current cookie looks like this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
    0, // cookie lifetime
    '/en/manager/' // <<-- the interested part, the path
    '' // domain
    false, // insecure
    false // allow javascript to use this cookie
);
```

with this settings, admins are able to login only via /en/managers/ url,
if they will use another url, for example /fr/managers/ - they will not be able to login.
How to setup a single cookie with the path with "dynamic" (language code is the parameter, which allows different urls to the admin panel) prefix?
Is it possible?

Comment: do you have a lot of lang folders? a dedicated function could handle the creation/removal of multiple cookies based on available langs

Comment: I am having about 10 different languages, but those are not folders. It is mod_rewrite.

Comment: or if it's easy to change in your code, you could consider changing path to  `/manager/{lang}/` so that you only have to set one cookie for `/manager` and subfolders